# Filter array with variable and keep results

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have and array:

```
Array(
  [9533]=>44
  [6478]=>56
)
```

I want to filter the array with a variable. I have tried this:

```
function filterArray($value){
    return ($value == $myVar);
}

$filteredArray = array_filter($myArray, 'filterArray');
print_r($filteredArray);
```

it just prints:

```
array()
```

if I change the variable to a hard number like 44, then it will give me what I want.

```
Array(
  [9533]=>44
)
```

Comment: From where `$myVar` is coming?

Comment: the `filterArray` doesn't know what `$myVar` you are looking to match.

Comment: This is where closures with a "use" are particularly useful: $myVar = 44; $filteredArray = array_filter($myArray, function($value) use ($myVar) { return $value == $myVar; } );

Comment: You probably want to declare `global $myVar;` in the beginning of `filterArray()`

Comment: @alfasin no please, don't incite him to use `global`...

Comment: @MarkBaker should be an answer instead of a comment :) (http://codepad.viper-7.com/kAtlty)

Comment: @j0k - posting it as an answer, just to offset the fact that he's been given an answer using global

Answer (score 3):

Don't use globals, that's [a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087/php-global-in-functions)

```
$myVar = 44; 
$filteredArray = array_filter( $myArray, 
                               function($value) use ($myVar) {
                                   return $value == $myVar;
                               }
                             );
```

Answer (score 0):

If `$myVar` is defined outside of the `filterArray` callback function, you need to declare it `global` within the function before you can use it.  So if you change your `filterArray` callback to this, then it should work:

```
function filterArray($value){
    global $myVar;
    return ($value == $myVar);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2268aee26dbde0d2d74b03d8cd658ef1aa0c44e2)

Try to avoid using the `global` keyword when you don't need to.  For most functions you can pass the variable as an argument instead.  In your case, the `global` is necessary since `array_filter` does not allow callbacks with parameters.

Comment: I said, *no please, don't incite him to use `global`...*

Comment: Would you like to explain why it's such a bad idea instead of just downvoting?  Obviously they're considered bad practice but this really isn't a situation where it will hurt.

Comment: If he starts to learn PHP, it will be preferable that he doesn't try to use `global` every time he wants to retrieve a variable that isn't in the scope of the function. It will become hard and hard to maintain and understand his code. I never used `global` and every code I read don't use `global`.

Comment: Thanks for all the quick responses. I cannot declare the variable right before the function because the variable is a user input. Global works great! Please explain why I shouldnt use it.

Comment: A more detailled answer why [`global` is evil](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5166527/569101)

Comment: @j0k the fact that we should not encourage him to use globals does not mean that you should downvote a correct answer. +1 from me!